# How use Append Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i wanted **DorodownmenuList** is append Button......
i wanted **[this](http://www.bootply.com/pVSNrNpOcM)**

1. First Step, I wanted **ul li** is append To ***Button*** when it is ***click***.
2. After ***dropdownmenu*** is **hide**.

***html***

```
<div class="input-group-btn">

 <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse">
    <span class="current" data-url="">Submenu1</span> <span class="right">&nabla;</span>
 </button>

 <ul id="categories" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="unicode ieUnicode">Submenu6</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

***css***

```
 .input-group-btn{
    position:relative;
 }
 .btn{
   width:300px;
   background-color:#ddd;
   color:red;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:20px;
   text-align:left;
   cursor:pointer;
 }
.btn .right{
   color:#fff;
   background-color:#000;
   border-radius:50%;
   display:inline-block;
   padding:0 5px;
  float:right;
}
.dropdown-menu{
   background-color: #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   list-style: none outside none;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 34px;
   width: 300px;
   display:block;
   display:none;

 }
```

***jquery***

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
   //how use li appendto btn and dropdown-menu is hide
```

});

it is what i want. how use jquery..

1. when I click ***Submen2*** 
      it is append ***button***

[image]
[image]
[image]

2. when I click ***Submen3***   
    it is append ***button***

[image]
[image]

## [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/gpj9f/)

Comment: Can u explain your question again.What is it that you want ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the button from the previous selection?

Comment: yes! i wanted li is appendTo .btn Class.  It is  same listBox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
$(this).parent().addClass('open');
//how use li appendto btn and dropdown-menu is hide
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
   $('#categories li').find('.right').remove();
   if($(this).find('.right').length<=0)
   {
   $(this).append('<span class="right">∇</span>');
   }
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gpj9f/4/)

EDIT for updated question:-

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
$(this).parent().addClass('open');
//how use li appendto btn and dropdown-menu is hide
});
$('#categories li').click(function(){
  $('.input-group-btn').removeClass('open');
  $('.current').text($(this).find('a').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    //how use li appendto btn and dropdown-menu is hide
});
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){
    $(this).append('<span class="right">∇</span>');

});

.btn .right, li .right{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;
    float:right;
}
```

don't forget to like if it was helpfull

Comment: please give me fiddle example

Comment: just go to your fiddle code replace jquery code with above code and edit .btn .right class and add li .right ..i have tested it in fiddle but forgot to save